# About network provider on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gps

I have a small question about Android.
I'm programming an application to get the location with `GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, when I testing the app on my mobile, I have a problem:
If I disable the widget location in the cell which is in the top bar, that off my `GPS` only or also the `NETWORK_PROVIDER`? because when I turn it gives me like `NETWORK_PROVIDER` are not enabled.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: That may depend on your phone model/OS/version etc

Comment: Please explain clearly.. what exactly you are getting issues?? You  device may be not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok friends, i want to tell us it was like I thought, if you disabled the widget location on the top bar of android, disables all modes of location (GPS and NETWORK_PROVIDER).